# jQuery - Waiting for the fadeOut to complete before running fadeIn

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if the is any way to wait until the fadeOut is complete before the fadeIn commences, as when i run the following code, it places one div under the other, then when its faded out it moves up ... looks a little ugly.

Code is as follows:

```
$('.sidebarform').fadeOut('slow');
$('.sidebarsuccess').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function has a callback that it executes when the animation is done:

```
$('.sidebarform').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.sidebarsuccess').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: keep in mind that if your selector is too general, the completion function will fire for every element when it is totally faded out, so if there are some already hidden, it will fire immediately.

Comment: I've used the :visible selector to combat the problem described by @box86rowh. See: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 36):

Another option is using promise which will wait for all pending animations on .sidebarform to complete first even if they were started elsewhere:

```
$('.sidebarform').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
    $('.sidebarsuccess').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Although the other answer has the green checkmark, I believe this answer solves my problem more specifically.

Comment: Just to help new users with the difference here, if there are X elements with the `sidebarform` class, in the accepted answer, the callback function will be called for each of them. If you have, for instance, `console.log('HERE');` in your callback, you'll see HERE in console X number of times. The promise tells jQuery to do something in a period of time relating to the attached function (fadeOut), and `done()` tells it that the promise is to run when it's has fully completed (is done, duh). In this way, you could have a fadeOut cb that changes the innerhtml, and a done cb that alerts console.

Comment: This solved my issue where the fadeout callback was executed immediately due to already hidden elements. This method seems to always wait which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery's Queues - allows you to put anything on the `fx` stack (and canceling works with it as well, no need for a finalizing `.promise()`):

```js
$('.sidebarform').fadeOut('slow').queue(function(done) {
    $('.sidebarsuccess').fadeIn('slow');
    done();
}) .... other chained effects
```

if no further effects are used, `done()` can be removed. `.queue()` will hold the stack until `done()` is called - useful for async execution. It will not wait for fadeIn.

This will force the `fx` stack to wait for fadeIn as well (just as an additional example):

```js
$('.sidebarform').fadeOut('slow').queue(function(done) {
    $('.sidebarsuccess').fadeIn('slow', done);
}) .... other chained effects kicking in after fadeIn
```

The queue will only continue, when the fadeIn completes and calls done as its callback - which is the queues one. The stack sees this as one entry.